# Sinatra Session Not Persisting On Post

Tags: ruby, nginx, sinatra, session-cookies, puma

I am currently running a sinatra app using puma and an nginx reverse proxy.  Sessions and cookies persist fine on any get requests as seen by logging:

```
{"user_id"=>1, "session_id"=>"89bb966142230a06fb5103db746c3011a741d88c7759dc2bff00c6bdd597c946"}
```

The user_id being the important part that signifies the session maintained its info.  However as soon as I attempt to post through a form I instead lose this critical info:

```
"POST /price HTTP/1.0" 302 - 0.0045
{"session_id"=>"89bb966142230a06fb5103db746c3011a741d88c7759dc2bff00c6bdd597c946"}
```

My sinatra config for sessions is:

```
use Rack::Session::Cookie, :key => 'rack.session',
                       :path => '/',
                       :secret => ENV['secret']
```

Which seems to be working fine in all other scenarios of the app.

My Nginx reverse proxy settings for this app are:

```
server {
  root /var/www/app/public;
  access_log /var/www/app/var/log/nginx_access.log;
  error_log /var/www/app/var/log/nginx_error.log;


  location / {
    try_files $uri @app;
  }

  location @app {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass http://admin_server;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    proxy_cookie_domain localhost $http_host;
  }

  #certbot ssl stuff
}
```

I'm at a relative loss now, as every other aspect of the authentication checks and session persistance seem to work fine, but the form post falls apart.  Any guidance and help would be immensely helpful!

Comment: Is it possible that you are running into a CSRF (Cross-Site Request Forgery) protection mechanism? Not sure how it works in Sinatra but you might have missed adding an authenticity token hidden field in your form.

Comment: Does the problem happen when you post directly to the app instead of through Nginx? It'd be useful to eliminate that as a source of the problem.